# test_can_withdraw() not working in Brownie

Tags: solidity, remix, python, testing, brownie

*Struggling with testing my withdraw function in a Solidity smart-contract via Brownie:*

My withdrawing function is the following but **in Remix it definitely works** and I have tested `_owner.send()` and `_owner.transfer()` as well and both work so it has to be the test but I can not see where my error lays.

```
function withdrawMoney() external onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    (success, response) = _owner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    return success;
}
```

Below the **brownie test that does not work**. The prints and other stuff should be explained in the comments.

```
def test_can_withdraw():

   # ARRANGE
   buy_coffee = deploy_buycoffee()  # works fine as contract is deployed

   # ACT
   print("Before: ", buy_coffee.balance())  # Before:  0

   tx = send_money()  # works fine as tested by sending {"from": get_account(account_index=1)}

   tx.wait(1)
   print("During: ", buy_coffee.balance())  # During:  1000000000000000

   tx = buy_coffee.withdrawMoney({"from": get_account(account_index=0)})  # BROKEN!

   tx.wait(1)
   print("After: ", buy_coffee.balance())  # should be 0 but is 1000000000000000

   # ASSERT
   assert buy_coffee.balance() == 0
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the gas by hand? One never knows...

Comment: I have not but does that mean you would deem my test to be set up correctly on first glance?

Comment: I don't use brownie, so I can't really say, but since nobody answered, it seems others can't either. You should give more information or even upload something to play with. Trying to come up with a minimal (not) working example might even reveal the solution right away.

Comment: I have discontinued this project, thank you for your suggestion though! Might get back to it at some point..